# How to match the hand shape of 2 binary images in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to make a hand gesture mouse and finally I've succeeded to extract the hand bw shape from rgb image.

Now my problem is how to match hand shape?

I have an image like this:

[image]

with new one picked from camera like these:

[image]
[image]

I have tried SURF features but it can't find features even with clenched hand!

Comment: please upload your example photos to a place that is **publicly** accessible.

Comment: SURF won't work on binary images, since you need some gradient from them to work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so what is the method to match these binary images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know where people will place their hands, you can could simply add up the pixel values and compare them against a threshold (or calibrate them for each hand in no time).

Let us assume your hand images are loaded into a 2D array (3D array is a trivial extension), called `handImage`

1. Compute the sum of all of the pixels for the hand closed

   `handclosed = sum(handImage1(:));`
2. Compute the sum of all the pixels for the hand open

   `handopen = sum(handImage2(:));`
3. Assuming that there is more white on your image for an open hand, we will assume that `handopen` > `handclosed`. Thus, we define

   `handthreshold = (handopen + handclosed) / 2`;
4. Finally, you will take the sum of your hand image for all subsequent images. If this sum is greater than the threshold, you assume the hand is open, otherwise you assume it is closed.

Comment: this is amazing thanks !
but if I want to identify the shape of the hand what is the technique to do this ?

Comment: This problem can be solved in many different ways; I just gave you one of the easiest ones I can think of. If you want to use a more elaborate approach, I suggest you look into machine learning: your problem is very similar to identifying hand-written numbers/letters. If you're looking for a good starting point, check out, for example, Andrew Ng's course on Machine Learnin, https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/info

Comment: thank you very much! I 've started this course a month ago but image processing field attracted me
really thank you for everything

Comment: My pleasure! Have fun, this is a fascinating topic. Cheers